# Why is the Enabled property of a custom CompositeControl still setting disabled="disabled" when the property is overridden?

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5, custom-server-controls

I have created a custom server control that inherits from CompositeControl.  In the CreateChildControls method, I add an input and a label control (there are others, too) to the control tree.  I have overridden the Enabled property so that I only get/set the input's Enabled property, not the composite control's Enabled property.  In the user control where I use this server control, I add `Enabled="false"` to the markup.  However, no matter what I do, the container div gets a `disabled="disabled"` attribute added to it (and so do some of the children).

Of course, this seems to work just fine in all browsers except IE 6.  If there's a fieldset legend or a radio button list inside the disabled control, the text disappears.  I was originally trying to see if there was some defect to fix via CSS for IE 6.  Then, I noticed the `disabled="disabled"` on tags I didn't even think were valid to have that attribute.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Sample control that exhibits behavior:

```
public class TextBoxWithLabel : CompositeControl
{
    private readonly Label _label = new Label();
    private readonly TextBox _textBox = new TextBox();

    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div; }
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return _label.Text; }
        set { _label.Text = value; }
    }

    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _textBox.Enabled; }
        set { _textBox.Enabled = value; }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        _label.ID = ID + "_label";
        _textBox.ID = ID + "_field";
        _label.AssociatedControlID = _label.ID;

        Controls.Add(_label);
        Controls.Add(_textBox);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<test:TextBoxWithLabel id="tester" runat="server" LabelText="My TextBox" Enabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a "new" Enabled property instead of overriding.

```
public new bool Enabled
{
    get { return _textBox.Enabled; }
    set { _textBox.Enabled = value; }
}
```

I won't accept this answer unless I get up-votes from others verifying my finding for the need to do this.

Comment: This makes sense. The property itself probably doesn't do anything in CompositeControl. Instead it would be read in the Render method (or something like that, I haven't read the source). By creating a new property, ((CompositeControl)this).Enabled would still read as true.

Comment: Is this unique to how CompositeControl is written? I'm thinking that this behavior wouldn't be seen if I wrote the control from scratch and used the Render method.  I'll have to dig into the framework code to find out.